# the distance between x and 1 is at least 1/2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In an exercise I'm asked to transform some statements to a mathematical notation, for example: *"the distance between x and 1 is 1/2"* can be transformed into |x-1|=1/2.

But I have a problem understanding one statement: *"the distance between x and 1 is at least 1/2"*

Does it mean this: $$|x-1|\geq1/2$$

+Rhanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct about it.

Comment: @Hawk  Why is $|x-1|\leq1/2$ not an equivalent statement?

Comment: The one you are asking about is the maximum distance between two points is less than $\dfrac12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The distance between x and 1 is at least $\frac{1}{2}$" is equivalent with "$|x-1|$ is at least $\frac{1}{2}$". Let $|x-1|=t$, than the sentence would be "$t$ is at least $\frac{1}{2}$", so the smallest value of $t$ is  $\frac{1}{2}$ ($t$ can be bigger that that). Mtahematicaly it is $t\geq\frac{1}{2}$ or $|x-1|\geq\frac{1}{2}$. So you are right.